# How can I iterate though this JSON using php/laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I need to be access each level. I am using laravel blade and php. I have been trying a few different way with no success, here is an example of what I tried:

```
@foreach($exercisePlan as $al)
   @if(isset($al->exercises))
     <li>{{$al->exercise->description}}</li>
   @endif
@endforeach
```

Here is my Json, I would be very grateful if someone could help me out here. Thanks in advance!

```
{
      "id": 1,
      "userID": 1,
      "exercisePlanID": 1,
      "updated_at": null,
      "created_at": null,
      "exercises": [
        {
          "id": 1,
          "planID": 1,
          "trainerID": "1",
          "day": "Monday",
          "exercise": [
            {
              "id": 1,
              "name": "Concentration Curls",
              "bodyPart": "Arm",
              "muscle": "Bicep",
              "description": "While sitting on a bench with your feet firmly on the floor, place the back of your left upper arm on the inside of your thigh. Keep your arm on your thigh throughout. Put your right hand on the right knee for stability. Do your curls on the left side, then repeat on the right side. ",
              "video": "https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=ebqgIOiYGEY",
              "created_at": null,
              "updated_at": null
            }
          ],
          "reps": "10",
          "sets": "5",
          "priority": "1",
          "weight": "10kg",
          "created_at": null,
          "updated_at": null
        },
        {
          "id": 2,
          "planID": 1,
          "trainerID": "2",
          "day": "Monday",
          "exercise": [
            {
              "id": 2,
              "name": "Preacher Curls",
              "bodyPart": "Arm",
              "muscle": "Bicep",
              "description": "Using a regular preacher bench, grab an EZ Curl bar with both hands using an underhand grip (palms facing upwards). Slowly curl the bar up to the top and bring it a few inches from your chin. Return the weight back down with a slow and controlled tempo to the starting position, allowing some resistance (negative) on the way back down. Repeat the movement for the desired number of repetitions.",
              "video": "https:\/\/www.youtube.com\/watch?v=fIWP-FRFNU0",
              "created_at": null,
              "updated_at": null
            }
          ],
          "reps": "5",
          "sets": "5",
          "priority": "2",
          "weight": "15kg",
          "created_at": null,
          "updated_at": null
        }
      ]
    }
```

Edit now getting error:Undefined variable: exercise:

```
            @foreach($exercisePlan as $al)
                @if(isset($al->exercises))
                    @foreach($al->$exercises as $exercise)
                        <li>{{$exercise->description}}</li>
                    @endforeach
                @endif
            @endforeach
```

Comment: Exercises is an array, so you need another `foreach` on it. Then you can get the description.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy well, it looks like exercise is an array too, for some reason

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Updated but still cant get it. Im trying 3 foreaches now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it:

```
                @foreach($exercisePlan as $plan)
                    @foreach($plan->exercises as $exercises)
                        @foreach($exercises->exercise as $exercise)
                            {{$exercise->name}}
                        @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                @endforeach
```